# Phone number prefix jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to prefix the phone number with a + sign when the user starts entering the phone number in the form.How to i do it using jquery without using the mask plugin.I have tried using mask plugin but will need a jquery library reference.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a pretty simple solution to force a leading + sign

[Working DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/epj4mrne/)

```
$(function () {
    $("input").on("input propertychange", function () {
    if ($(this).val().indexOf("+") === -1) {
        $(this).val("+" + $(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```